# CS7069: Reference to type 'CodeCompileUnit' claims it is defined in 'System', but could not be found

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, razor, codedom

I am trying to compile razor html templates for the usage in a webbrowser control in Microsoft .net Framework 4 Development. Everything is fine until I want to call "codeProvider.GenerateCodeFromCompileUnit". The IDE says that the type reference to type CodeCompileUnit is mssing in System, even though I am able to declare a CodeCompileUnit on my own ...

I already checked the references, cleaned the solution, tried to restart the IDE and stuff like that but nothing seems to fix the problem.

I don't really know how to go on. Here is the current code:

```
public static Assembly Compile(IEnumerable<RazorTemplateModel> models)
{
  var builder = new StringBuilder();
  var codeProvider = new CSharpCodeProvider();
  using (var writer = new StringWriter(builder))
  {
    foreach (var razorTemplateModel in models)
    {
      GeneratorResults generatorResults = GenerateCode(razorTemplateModel);
      codeProvider.GenerateCodeFromCompileUnit(generatorResults.GeneratedCode, writer, new CodeGeneratorOptions());
    }
  }

  var result = codeProvider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(BuildCompilerParameters(), new[] { builder.ToString() });
  if (result.Errors != null && result.Errors.Count > 0)
    throw new RazorTemplateCompileException(result.Errors, builder.ToString());

  return result.CompiledAssembly;
}
```

The following error message is shown for Line 10 of the code:

[ErrorMessage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mWKTP.png)

Here is a screenshot of my System references in the project:

[SystemReferences](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IZLfR.png)

Can anybody help?

Edit: Forgot to mention that I am using the references in an Mono.Android Project with Xamarin.Android.Support.v4

Comment: All NuGet packages are updated? Can you check please?

Comment: Yeah, I already reinstalled the multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

That's present under `System.CodeDOM` namespace and so you will have to add `using System.CodeDOM;` probably. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.codecompileunit(v=vs.110).aspx

Also, can you check the version of `System` dll you have referenced.

Comment: Yeah I know, I've got the corresponding usings:

Comment: using System.CodeDom; and using System.CodeDom.Compiler;

Comment: System Version is: 2.0.5.0, Compiled against .net v4.0.30319 runtime

Comment: @epanalepsis No, make sure you are using same version of `System` as of your target framework version

Comment: Since I am using Mono.Android because it's an android application I guess that won't be possible. :/ There aren't supported v4.0.0.0 references.

Comment: @epanalepsis then change your target framework version (lower down) accordingly

Comment: Do you know which Android API Level is required?